# Create Generic method that returns sort lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, expression

I created a method that returns a lambda statement in order to use in `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` linq methods.

The line that I want to use sort expression is like:

```
var results = _dbSet.AsNoTracking()
                    .OrderByDescending(sort)
                    .ToList();
return results;
```

I want to set "sort" parameter using this method:

```
public static Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> GetSortExpression<TEntity>(string propertyName)
{
        var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "entity");
        var prop = Expression.Property(item, propertyName);
        var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, object>>(prop, item);

        return selector;
}
```

But it throws error for "double" property like "Product.Price"

> System.ArgumentException: 'Expression of type 'System.Double' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'

I couldn't find where the problem is.....

Comment: Is this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet/233505#233505

Comment: I'm confused why you're returning an `Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>` instead of the `IQueryably<TEntity>`. I've done several projects with sorting/filtering capabilities. Only once did I ever have to override and create my own Expression Tree, and that was for a very complex, combining filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a call to `Convert` to handle any type (boxing as necessary). This is not necessarily as efficient as knowing the type...

```
public static Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> GetSortExpression<TEntity>(string propertyName)
{
        var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "entity");
        var prop = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(item, propertyName), typeof(object));
        var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, object>>(prop, item);

        return selector;
}
```

Using LINQPad you can create a sample `Expression` variable and then `Dump()` its contents to see how the compiler handles certain situations.

For example, by using

```
Expression<Func<double, object>> f = p => p;
f.Dump();
```

You will see the compiler inserts an `UnaryExpression` `Convert` into the body to convert from `double` to `object`.

Answer (score 0):

You may rewrite your method as the following adding TKey

```
public static Expression<Func<TEntity, TKey>> GetSortExpression<TEntity, TKey>(string propertyName)
{
        var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "entity");
        var prop = Expression.Property(item, propertyName);
        var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, TKey>>(prop, item);

        return selector;
}
```

So, you can use it as

```
_dbSet.AsNoTracking()
                    .OrderByDescending(GetSortExpression<Enitity, double>("Price"))
                    .ToList();
```

As I understand your intention it does not solve what you want. Probably you want it to be universal method that accept any field. To support it you need to do a more complex work. First, you should know a field type and depending on it create set of calls for Int, Double and etc.

```
switch (<field type>) {

case <type is double>:
  return _dbSet.AsNoTracking()
                        .OrderByDescending(GetSortExpression<Enitity, double>(FieldName))
                        .ToList();

case <type is int>:
  return _dbSet.AsNoTracking()
                        .OrderByDescending(GetSortExpression<Enitity, int>(FieldName))
                        .ToList();
```

As alternative you may create your SQL query manually adding any sorting and execute it as:

```
your_dbcontext.Database.SqlQuery<TEntity>("your query order by field");
```